# Servlet esta dando erro 404

Tags: java, aplicação-web, servlet, jee, servlet-3

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação de postagens, começei a estudar agora o Java Web e toda vez que vou executar o servlet no Apache 8 o aparece uma página de erro 404.

meu servlet

```
 package app.web4.servlets;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 import app.web4.model.Post;

 @WebServlet(name="post", urlPatterns="/user/post")
 public class postServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public postServlet() 
{

}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

        throws ServletException, IOException {

    createPost(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    createPost(request, response);
}

private void createPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String postText = request.getParameter("postText");
    String userName = "";

    if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
        userName = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    }

    try {
        Post post = new Post(postText, userName);

        List<Post> posts = (List<Post>) getServletContext().getAttribute("posts");

        if (posts == null) {
            posts = new ArrayList<>();
            posts.add(post);
            getServletContext().setAttribute("posts", posts);
        }else {
            posts.add(post);
            getServletContext().setAttribute("posts", posts);
        }

        request.setAttribute("posts", posts);


        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/home.jsp").forward(request, response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Houve algum erro com o seu post");
    }
}
 }
```

a chamada que eu faço a ele através do arquivo NewPost.jsp

```
    <div class="container ">
    <form action="post" method="POST" class="form-inline">
        <input name="postText" type="text"
            class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"
            placeholder="What's on your mind?">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Testei com servlets mais simples, que só iriam levar para uma página com um " oi", porem da o mesmo erro 404.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: A action deve apontar para o servlet e não `action="post"`

Comment: Quando eu uso o action="post" ele envia para o url correto do servlet, mas apresenta 404. Quando eu vou no eclipse e mando executar o Servlet diretamente, da o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A url para a sua Servlet é `/user/post`.

De acordo com o [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) do `@WebServlet`, as propriedades `value` e `urlPatterns` que servem pra mapear a URL da Servlet.
O `name` é apenas o nome da Servlet.

```
<div class="container ">
    <form action="/user/post" method="POST" class="form-inline">
        <input name="postText" type="text"
            class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"
            placeholder="What's on your mind?">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Se você estiver usando JSP na view:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/post" method="POST" class="form-inline">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Quando faço isso ele envia direto para localhost:8080/user/post e não localhost:8080/TwitterWeb4/user/post.

também falaram para eu tentar "user/post" na chama.da, mas ai me chama um  localhost:8080/user/user/post.

Comment: Eu editei a minha resposta, vê se resolve o seu problema.